# Firebase NullPointerException al usar setText()

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase

Tengo problemas a la hora de usar algunos datos de Firebase despues de hacer login con una cuenta de Google. La idea es coger el nombre, correo e imagen del usuario para luego mostrarlo, pero a la hora se hacer un .setText(firebaseUser.getDisplayName) y demas me salta el error NullPointerException.

> Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.musicae/com.example.musicae.View.NavigationBarWithTabsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
>           at com.example.musicae.View.NavigationBarWithTabsActivity.setUser(NavigationBarWithTabsActivity.java:82)
>           at com.example.musicae.View.NavigationBarWithTabsActivity.onCreate(NavigationBarWithTabsActivity.java:46)

Me deja iniciar sesion y me deja coger los datos ya que he hecho un Log.d y me muestra el Logcat.

```
Log.d("MiAPP", firebaseUser.getDisplayName());
        Log.d("MiAPP", firebaseUser.getEmail());
        Log.d("MiAPP", firebaseUser.getPhotoUrl().toString());
```

Log.d por Logcast:
[image: Logcat]

Mi código, NavigationBarWithTabsActivity.java:

```
public class NavigationBarWithTabsActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


public ImageView userImage;
public TextView userName;
public TextView userEmail;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation_bar_with_tabs);

    setUp();
}

public void setUp() {
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

    TapPagerAdapter tapPagerAdapter = new TapPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(tapPagerAdapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();


    setUser();
}

public void setUser(){
    userImage = findViewById(R.id.userimage);
    userName =  findViewById(R.id.username);
    userEmail =  findViewById(R.id.useremail);

    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if (firebaseUser != null) {
        Log.d("MiAPP", firebaseUser.getDisplayName());
        Log.d("MiAPP", firebaseUser.getEmail());
        Log.d("MiAPP", firebaseUser.getPhotoUrl().toString());
        userName.setText(firebaseUser.getDisplayName());
        userEmail.setText(firebaseUser.getEmail());
        Glide.with(this)
                .load(firebaseUser.getPhotoUrl().toString())
                .into(userImage);


        findViewById(R.id.logoutBtn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                AuthUI.getInstance()
                        .signOut(NavigationBarWithTabsActivity.this)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class));
                                finish();
                            }
                        });
            }
        });
    }
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        goToReportSection();
    }
    if (id == R.id.action_help) {
        goToHelpSection();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void goToHelpSection(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SlideActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void goToReportSection(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ReportActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_music) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NavigationBarWithTabsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_account) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AccountActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

LoginActivity:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 123;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    findViewById(R.id.signInBtn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            signIn();
        }
    });

    comeIn();
}

void comeIn(){
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if (firebaseUser != null) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, NavigationBarWithTabsActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
}

void signIn(){
    startActivityForResult(
            AuthUI.getInstance()
                    .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                    .setAvailableProviders(Arrays.asList(
                            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build()))
                    .build(),
            RC_SIGN_IN);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            comeIn();
        }
    }
}
```

}

activity_navigation_bar_with_tabs.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/colorWhite"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/colorWhite"
    android:background="@color/backgroundMenu"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/logoutBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/buttonBlue"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="@string/log_out"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

nav_header_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/userImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/nav_header_desc"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="@string/nav_header_title"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userEmail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/nav_header_subtitle" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Estos son todos los Layout que tengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cuál es la solución a todos los errores NullPointerException presentes, pasados y futuros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-soluci%c3%b3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados)

Comment: Debes revisar si los textView existen realmente bajo esos id en el layout, este y todos los demás: ` userImage = findViewById(R.id.userImage);`, por cierto, declaras dos veces el último textView.

Comment: Los TextView si que estan creados y tienen esa id en particular.

Comment: Estas seguro de que cuando haces `setContentView` apunta a ese layout en el `onCreate` de `NavigationBarWithTabsActivity`? Tambien revisa si el tipo de la vista en la clase es `TextView`. Comparte el codigo del onCreate de `NavigationBarWithTabsActivity`.

Comment: Estoy seguro de que es TextView. Y ahora que lo mensiona en `onCreate` solo tengo `setContentView` del layout de mi `NavigationBarWithTabsActivity`. El caso es que al crear un Navigation bar te crea varios layouts y estoy intento porner los datos del usuario en un layout diferente al de `NavigationBarWithTabsActivity` ¿Eso podria ser el problema?

Comment: si tus TextView no estan dentro del layout que llama el setContentView, va a existir una referencia nula a esos componentes, por lo que el setText en tu TextView va a dar null ya que el TextView nunca lo referencias

Comment: Un poco extraño, veo que nav_header_main.xml se contiene dentro de activity_navigation_bar_with_tabs.xml y se deberìa obtener la referencia del TextView. @KennedyRC

Comment: El error es que no estas haciendo `include` del layout  `nav_header_main.xml` que es donde se encuentran las referencias que quieres buscar en el Activity. Intenta hacer el include de dicho layout en el layout `activity_navigation_bar_with_tabs.xml`, ya que el include que tienes ahi es `app_bar_main` y ahi no es donde se encuentran las referencias que quieres buscar, por eso te devuelve `null`.